# How to add relationship between database table in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I want to do like this when user register the account, the details will save into 2 database table. Based on the image given below, I want to link the relationship between id with user_id:

[image]

So when I go to **phpmyadmin**, I click at **user_id** it will redirect me to see the user table details based on the **id**.

Here is my code:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  $user= User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $employee= Employee::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried any of the following https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank yes, I have try it but it will come out error

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Can you also include your migrations for the employee's table? Also, tips, you can use your `$user` variable to create an Employee if you define Employee's relationship correctly using `$user->employee()-> create(...)`

Comment: @sta I use version 7.4

Comment: @felixbmmm include  migrations for the employee's table?

Comment: I mean add your employee's migration to the question

Comment: @qing you need to add fillable property `protected $fillable = ['user_id','username','email'];` on your Employee model

Comment: @sta I have add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Eloquent [One to One](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation like this :

**app\Models\User.php**

```
public function employee()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**app\Models\Employee.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id','username','email'];
```

Now change your function to :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
  ]);

  $user->employee()->create([
      'username' => $data['name'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I have column user_id in my employee database table. Now I get this error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `employee` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `user_user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Answer (score 0):

If you issue with creating the model using relationships. You can add `user_id` to data while creating

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $employee = Employee::create([
        'username' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Before that I doing like this but when I go to phpmyadmin, I check the table is not link together

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is regarding phpmyadmin and not the relationships in laravel.

When creating the table, is the migration using a forign key?

For example something similar to this on your emoloyee table

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

This is what creates a forign key in the database, rather than a relationship in laravel.